# Добавить в массив новое свойство (подмассив). JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как мне в один массив добавить несколько (свойств) / подмассивов ?

Например, есть данные:

```
 [яблоко, груша, апельсин]
```

Есть еще данные:

```
 [помидоры, огурцы, морковь]
```

И вот я хочу создать массив в котором будут два подмассива, фрукты и овощи
и потом вызывать нужные мне данные таким образом:

```
console.log(product.fruct[0]) /// рез - яблоко
console.log(product.ovosh[0]) /// рез - помидор
```

У меня есть цикл в котором берутся все эти овощи и фрукты 
вот как мне добавить разные подмассивы?

```
var product = [];
for ...... {
var ovosh = ovosh[i];
var fruct = fruct[i];
product = ?
}
 console.log(product.fruct[0])
```

Comment: просто присвойте масив в свойство вашего `prosuct` так :`prosuct.ovosh = arr`

Comment: product.push(text);   а вот у меня проблема в том что данные вставляеются через функцию push, как тут добавить свойсвто ovosh ?

Comment: что-то я у вас в вопросе не вижу `push`

Comment: все разобрался сам, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

это скорее всего вам нужно сделать product  обектом

вот пример

```
var ovosh = ['помидор'];
var fruct = ['яблока'];
var product = {ovosh:[],fruct:[]};
for (var index in ovosh) {
    product.ovosh.push(ovosh[index]);
}
for (var index2 in fruct) {
    product.fruct.push(fruct[index2]);
}
```

> console.log(product.fruct[0]) после этого вызвав эту функцию у вас будет значение 'яблоко'

рекомендую вам прочесть урок 
https://learn.javascript.ru/object